# HTML tags in objective c programming

Tags: objective-c

Is there any function in Objective-C to print a list of elements as unordered HTML elements. For ex - [@"a--b-c---d" htmlList: @"--"] returns @ "

- a
- b-c
- -d

"

the "--" is the delimiter to seperate the string of elements. I have used NSSArray to store the input string and function componentsSeperatedByString:@"--" to get the elements. How do I go ahead in adding the HTML tags li and /li between elements and ul and /ul at the end of the entire list?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing built in for this but it is not difficult to write. Look at the documentation for NSString an NSArray.